# Update nuget current version through Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I couldn't upgrade current version of nuget using following command in Package Manager Console but it gives me following errors

```
PM> Install-Package NuGet.Client -Version 4.3.0-beta1-2418
Install-Package : Не удалось найти версию "4.3.0-beta1-2418" пакета "NuGet.Client".
строка:1 знак:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  NuGet.Client -Version 4.3.0-beta1-2418
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

How I can upgrade current version of nuget using Package Manager Console ??
Не удалось найти версию "4.3.0-beta1-2418" пакета "NuGet.Client". This means it can' find this kind of version but in nuget web site it gives me following version of program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Visual Studio

```
Open Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates > Visual Studio Gallery
Select NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio [Year]
```

`Updates` will only be shown in these menus if you do not have the latest supported version of `NuGet` by the `IDE` installed: